# Tips for removing stuck screws from bottom of shower door?

Tags: shower

[image]My shower door is 7 years old. The door was getting stuck when I tried opening it from the inside and noticed that the sweep was warped. It's held in place by three metal screws (screwed into a metal strip). They seem to be hopelessly stuck.  I've tried cleaning off the hard water build up and have sprayed the screws with WD-40 and let it sit overnight.

I've tried placing a rubber band between the screw & screwdriver and have tried using a hammer and screwdriver to loosen the screws but they refuse to budge and I'm afraid of stripping the screws.  So far I've only used a  manual screw driver but it's hard to apply hard pressure when the shower door is still hanging on the hinges. Does anyone have experience with this sort of issue or can offer some good suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt WD-40 does much for calcium buildup. Vinegar, Lime-Away, etc would yield better results. Is there some reason you can't have one hand under the door applying force from the other side? If you do strip it, needlenose vice grips would break it free and then you could just get a new one. Best solution is to borrow an impact driver to help prevent stripping it yet have lots of torque.

Comment: old old question, but it looks to me like you have enough head sticking out to use a vice grip.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [manual impact driver](https://www.craftsman.com/products/craftsman-impact-driver) to break the screws free. You hit the back of this tool with a hammer and it creates up to 200 lbs/ft of torque.

Alternatively, you can grind a line through the center of the screw with a Dremel grinding disk and use a slotted screwdriver to loosen it if you strip out the Phillips drive.

[image: Craftsman manual impact driver]
[image: grinding notch with Dremel tool]